# Adding a second passport to Global Entry

Tags: global-entry

As a US federal government employee, when I travel on business I use a government passport that’s different from my personal passport. My Global Entry info is associated with my personal passport. Do I need to add my government passport to the Global Entry info, and if so, how?

Comment: Do you have to use your government passport to enter the US, or just for entry into the foreign countries you travel to?  If the latter you could just use your GE and personal passport when you re-enter the US.

Comment: Both entry and exit. I suppose I could also bring my personal passport and show that, but the problem is that the airlines are given the number of my government passport when the flight is booked. Depending on how they associate person with identification and global entry, I guess that the airline wouldn’t make the connection.

Comment: Have you asked your employer? Presumably they (the government) know how a government passport should be used...

Comment: If you access your TTP account does it allow you to add a second passport? I **swear** I saw an FAQ that implied that you could bring multiple passports to your enrollment interview so the information could be entered in the system, but now I can't find it.

Comment: @iayork I'm not referring to the airline, I'm talking about when you actually land in the US (after your flight) and enter US immigration could you just use your GE and enter under your personal passport?  Everything outside the US you could use your government pp, but when you get to the kiosks in the US use your GE.  I'm not sure if your employer requires you to use your gov pp here, but it might be an option

Comment: @Midavalo I might be able to use my personal passport through entry. But I'd also very much like to access TSA Pre, which needs the airline to sign off on it and indicate PRE on the boarding pass. So this approach would only solve half the problem (and at the admittedly minor cost of carrying two passports to lose and misplace)

Comment: @TripeHound As for asking my employer, just being a government employee doesn't magically make the government less opaque or more helpful ...

Comment: @mkennedy I too saw a FAQ implying that you could add multiple passports to my Global Entry profile, but can't find any way to actually do so

Comment: do you pass through any of the enrollment upon arrival airports? Maybe try to talk to someone there?